# Less specific class styles won't apply

Tags: html, css

I have a class called .dropdown which is used across the page. But for one of these drop downs, I want the bottom margin  to be 10px. So, in the html when I use

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
```

it works fine. However if I were to declare in my css file:

```
.ddMargin  { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

and then use it in my html:

```
<div class="dropdown ddMargin">
```

it doesn't seem to work. How can I make this extra class rule more specific?

```
.dropdown .ddMargin  { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

doesn't seem to work either.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminate the space

```
.dropdown.ddMargin  { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

This is how you select an element that has both classes on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no space when selecting an element that has multiple classes:

```
.dropdown.ddMargin  { margin-bottom: 10px; }
         ^
```